# ffmpeg acompress audio filter missing

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

I need to process a great quantity of mp3's files. I intend to make a BASH script to  compress dynamically these audios as a batch. Ubuntu ;)

I've got everything working but the line:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k  -af "acompressor=threshold=-17dB:ratio=5:attack=46:release=2700" testcomp.mp3
```

I get the message *`[AVFilterGraph @ 0x106dbe0] No such filter: 'acompresor'`*. Here it's the output of `$ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder

--------------------------------------
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Works fine on my end. Are you sure you didn't just mis-type? The error message mentions `'acompresor'` after all.

Comment: Nope. Using acompresor/acompressor, neither with advanced-filter. I think it's a version problem.

Comment: In fact i'm testing the 'compand' filter wich it's present in my version and I  think it' the compressor/expander filter for the dynamic compression. But the 'transfer function' i.e. ''points' it's exotic.
Thanks anyway.